# Image not getting loaded using UIL, volley or picasso

Tags: android

I was trying to load this image using various image loaders. But failed. Can anyone tell me the reason? I have tried another image url and that is working for each of them.
this is the url:  http://kbsi.in/images/books/gbp/front/i-have-a-dream.jpg

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly happens when you try to download the image?

Comment: Unexpected response code 403 for http://kbsi.in/images/books/gbp/thumb/i-have-a-dream.jpg - volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with AQuery.

```
AQuery mAquery = new AQuery(this);
mAquery.id(view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).image("http://kbsi.in/images/books/gbp/front/i-have-a-dream.jpg", true, true);
```

I tested and it works!